# Inserting Indicator in Video While Recording the Video?

Tags: android

I have to do simple task of recording video. Following is the my desired screen

[image]

while recording When Press Good Button Indicator In Recored video become Green and On Press on Wrog Button Indicator become RED.

How can I do this task?? If have code Please share. On Playback we want to see indicator.

And Also I want to trim some clips of long video and Join them.